# Show hide fieldsets greater than/less than on select change

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, show-hide

I have a form which is going to contain 4 fieldsets. The user must fill in a minimum of 1 fieldset but can choose to complete additional fieldsets. Each fieldset's contents are identical.

I want them to be able to choose a number of fieldsets to show from a dropdown. On selecting a number from the dropdown the relevant number of fieldsets appears.

So if they choose 3 from the quantity dropdown, the first 3 fieldsets should be shown. If they change their mind and drop to 2 fieldsets then the 3rd should hide again.

Here's the base HTML.

```
<form>
    <select id="quantity" name="quantity">
        <option disabled="disabled">xx</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>

    <fieldset id="fieldset_name_1">Form Area 1</fieldset>
    <fieldset id="fieldset_name_2" style="display: none;">Form Area 2</fieldset>
    <fieldset id="fieldset_name_3" style="display: none;">Form Area 3</fieldset>
    <fieldset id="fieldset_name_4" style="display: none;">Form Area 4</fieldset>

</form>​
```

And here's my **very** basic jQuery so far. I'm quite a noob to client side stuff, generally burying my head in php :)

```
var registerCount = function() {
    var qty = $(this).val();

    var fieldsets = $('fieldset');

    fieldsets.slice(0, qty ).show();  
}


$("#quantity").change(registerCount).keypress(registerCount);
```

So I've got it showing fieldsets correctly, I'm just not sure how to hide them on change or keypress again.

I'm sure this is simple but I think my familiarity with PHP keeps me trying to code things completely differently to the jQuery/javascript way.

Comment: I think you rather should dynamically create the fieldset elements instead of showing/hiding existing ones

Comment: @Bergi I probably should but each fieldset required a whole chunk of PHP to generate. I know I could work that into a JS solution for generating the fieldsets but I just don't have the time left on this job to spend more time on this form :(

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all the suggestions. I've got to focus on another job for the next couple of hours but will come back to this asap and select the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the unselected, you hide all before showing the selected:

```
fieldsets.hide().slice(0, +qty).show();
```

Comment: This works like a charm and is definitely the most succinct of the answers - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try hide all first and then show according to selection:

Sample:

```
var registerCount = function() {
    var qty = $(this).val();

    var fieldsets = $('fieldset');
    fieldsets.each(function (){
       $(this).hide();
    });

    fieldsets.slice(0, qty ).show();  
}

$("#quantity").change(registerCount).keypress(registerCount);
```

Comment: You never need a `each` in jQuery unless a closure is required to deal with single elements

Answer (score 0):

You can put the fieldset dynamically to not hide them.

```
$(function(){
    $('#quantity').change(function(){
        $('#fieldsets').html('');
        n = $(this).val();
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++){
            $('<fieldset/>', {
                id: 'fieldset_name_'+i,
                text: 'Form Area '+i
            }).appendTo('#fieldsets');
        }
    });
})​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JmeYZ/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer,

http://jsfiddle.net/mQ23q/

Hope it will help